# Sprite is Refreshing

Tags: java, android, animation

I am using "AndEngine" and I would like to know if I am following the best practice when I want to refresh the entity.

Let say, I have 2 sprites and I want change them into 2 another sprites.

I usually do it like this :

```
class MainClass {
    private Sprite sprite1;
    private Sprite sprite2;

    private void someMethod(){
        sprite1 = new Sprite(0,0,someRegion1,getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        sprite2 = new Sprite(10,10,someRegion2,getVertexBufferObjectManager());

        attachChild(sprite1);
        attachChild(sprite2);
    }

    private void refreshSprites(Sprite pSprite1, Sprite pSprite2){
        Sprite temp1 = sprite1;
        Sprite temp2 = sprite2;
        sprite1 = sprite2 = null;
        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                temp1.detachSelf();
                                temp2.detachSelf();
                            }
                        });
        sprite1 = pSprite1;
        sprite2 = pSprite2;

        attachChild(sprite1);
        attachChild(sprite2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with AndEngine, but here are some things that I saw:

Inside your `refreshSprites` method you call `detachSelf` and `attachChild` in unsynchronized way. So either make sure this method is called from `updateThread` or make all those operation in your Runnable class. Here is an example of the second choice.

```
private void refreshSprites(Sprite pSprite1, Sprite pSprite2){
        final Sprite oldSprite1 = sprite1;
        final Sprite oldSprite2 = sprite2;
        final Sprite newSprite1 = pSprite1;
        final Sprite newSprite2 = pSprite2;

        sprite1 = sprite2 = null;

        runOnUpdateThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                oldSprite1.detachSelf();
                                oldSprite2.detachSelf();
                                attachChild(newSprite1);
                                attachChild(newSprite2);
                            }
                        });

    }
```

Pay attention to the `final` that I am using, otherwise those values will not be available in the `oldSprite1` inner class.

And some small things

- `sprite1 = sprite2 = null;` you should place in it's own method, call it reset or some thing similar. It will improve your method [Single responsibility principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle)
- Pay attention to my choice of variables names: `oldSprite`, I think it explain the meaning of the variable better than `tmp`.

Comment: oo I totaly forget about sprite1.setVisible(false) I will edit my question :). Thanks for tip about variable naming but this is only for example. But in other hand this is code review so code should be elegant in any case :). Got to edit it.